# How to access a function which is not global and it exist in another js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js files and I want to access one function from another function but I call it in another js file. I receive this error when I call it `Uncaught ReferenceError: vidPause is not defined`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.controlls = function(opt) {
    ......
    function init() {
    .....
    }
    function vidPause(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       $.fn.controlls.toggleBarPlayingButtons('pause');
       video.pause();
    }
    .....
```

From this js file I want to call vidPause in the following function in another js file

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if (video) {
        $('video').controlls(vidPause());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: load 2nd js file first and then call 2nd js file function

Comment: This is how it is made. First is loading the the script.js then controlls.js

Comment: myFunction won't have access to vidPause because it's not accessible from an outer scope than your IIFE. You have to load your other file using s.getScript from example in order to make this work.

Comment: You simply can't access vars outside your scope

Comment: ok, and in the end is there any way to grab function which sits in another function?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is scope.

`init()` and `vidPause()` are private to the `(function($) {` call.  They will not be directly accessible the way you are trying to access them.

Many jquery plugins use text (not my preference, but that's how they work), eg $.dialog("open"), so you could do something like that (not sure if opt is meant to mean action, so update accordingly) :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.controlls = function(action, opt) {
        switch (action) {
            case "pause":
                vidPause(opt);
                break;
            ...
```

usage

```
$('video').controlls("pause");
```

---

It might be possible to add the methods as if using namespaces, but I've not seen this in plugins so depends on what you are doing with your plugin (ie releasing it) whether you want to be consistent, eg:

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.controlls = {};
    $.fn.controlls.pause = function(opt) {
        video.pause();
        ...
```

usage

```
$('video').controlls.pause()
```